# Using VBA to check PowerQuery source mod dates

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

I've been looking around and I can't find anything like this scenario.

I integrate files in multiple folders using PowerQuery. I'm using VBA to automate the weekly update process which includes refreshing the queries, saving a dated copy, yadda yadda.

Right now I have a query that lists the contents of the source file folders and I manually filtered it to show the files used in the queries. I added a conditional column to show if new source data needs to be updated. Some of the source files are reference tables that don't change and/or I don't care about the mod date. The ones I do care about are in specific folders.

What I want to do is use VBA to check the mod dates on the files and warn before it goes through the rest of the code. I know that I could code it manually but what I'd like to do is have it check through all the source files, check for ones that are in certain folders and display the names of the ones that need updating so I can reuse the code in different workbooks that use different source files.

My thought process is that you would loop through the queries, check the source file path and date, check for the criteria and return a message if any files aren't up to date.

I'm not an expert at VBA and this is what I've come up with and it of course doesn't work

```
Sub showsource()
Dim qfile As ODBCConnection
Dim qfilestr As String
Dim qconn As ListObject
'ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Item
qfile = ThisWorkbook.Queries.Item("FLPA Project Data")
qfilestr = qfile.SourceDataFile
'qfilestr = "" & Sheets("Files Used").QueryTables("Files Used").SourceConnectionFile & ""
Debug.Print qfilestr
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by ***"doesn't work***?

Comment: My apologies. I get a Run-time error '91 (Object variable or With block variable not set)  on "qfile = ThisWorkbook.Queries.Item("FLPA Project Data")"